# Docker environment for two similar projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose, development-environment, lamp, dockerfile

How to set up Docker environment for development of two similar web projects, with different versions of the similar software?

### Project A

- Debian Wheezy
- Apache 2.2
- MySQL 5.6
- PHP 5.4

### Project B

- Ubuntu LTS latest
- Apache 2.4
- MySQL 5.7
- PHP 7.0

### Both projects

- volume for web application source files
- apache mods: `rewrite` etc.
- editable vhost.conf file
- phpMyAdmin
- packages like `git-core`, `vim-nox`, `mc`, `phing`, `phpunit`, `openssh`
- persistent database, initally populated from .sql file
- UTF8 by default

What is the best way to do it assuming, that:

- there will be more similar projects developed at once on my host in the future
- I want to save maximum resources (disk space, memory and cpu)
- I prefer using base images (eg. `httpd:2.2` than `easyone:lamp`), because I have to emulate environment already present on production machines

Comment: How are you currently doing it?

Comment: @Rao So far I have managed to build a docker image using `Dockerfile`, running Debian, Apache and PHP. In this Docker config I can select the versions I need for the project. But this installs the reqired packages manually using `apt-get`.

Comment: I think, you need to setup vagrant for this purpose...